# Inner glow effect in WPF

Tags: wpf

Short question :)
Does anyone have a method for creating a Inner glow effect in WPF?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by this? Provide an example, maybe?

Comment: See the answer of Cameron. Thats the thing i would like to achieve indeed :) 

http://blogs.msdn.com/msmossyblog/archive/2008/09/15/how-to-make-innerglows-with-expression-blend.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google is your friend.

[How to: Make Innerglows with Expression Blend.](http://blogs.msdn.com/msmossyblog/archive/2008/09/15/how-to-make-innerglows-with-expression-blend.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Kaxaml.  The attribute d:IsHidden="True" is from a namespace that I've never seen before.  Is that a Blend thing?  Can we use that in Visual Studio as well?

Comment: The "d" namespace is xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008". I had trouble finding any info about it.

Comment: That blog has a terrible script on it that keeps forwarding me...urgh

Comment: `BitmapEffects` are noop since .Net 4, so this no longer work